# Issue with resuing the cell on UItableViewEditingStyleDelete

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am blocked with an issue on deleting multiple rows at a time. On the button click am setting the tableview editing style to YES. Then we can see the deleteAccesoryButton beside all the available cells. when we delete on of the cell and reload the data the deleteAccessoryButton remains in the delete mode. (FYR: check the attached image). When i stop reusing the cell and creating new cell i don't see issue. 
Is there any possibility to refresh the cell to normal mode by reusing the cell[image: Issues with reusing the customcell]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try overriding `-(void)prepareForReuse` in your UITableViewCell subclass and set the cell's `editing` property to `NO`.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    self.editing = NO;
}
```